# jquery at IE8 bug?? hide and show can't display normally

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I find in FF3.5, IE6, IE7 all work fine but only IE8...I don't which I should change.
the following is my html sample

```
<div id="L1">Menu1
<div id="menu1">
    <ul>
        <li>111</li>
        <li>122</li>
        <li>133</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
<div id="L1">Menu22222222222222222
<div id="menu2">
    <ul>
        <li>211</li>
        <li>222</li>
        <li>233</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

and I will detect id L1 click event, if I click L1, it's ul content will show,but L1/menu2 content will be hidden. But at same time, word "Menu2" will move up to the right of 133, ...of course I set the width of the menu.
I wish the html can be like

```
----------------
Menu 1
111 122
333
----------------
Menu222222
---------------
```

.but I still confuse why only IE8 can't work, but if the same line "133" , the extra space is can't large enough for Menu2xx, the Menu2xx will be at right position.

Comment: Your HTML looks suspiciously close to a bulleted list. Maybe you need to indent your code 4 spaces? :)

Comment: You don't close your `<div id="L1">` blocks. Also the `id` attribute should be unique to an element, you probably want to use `class="L1"`

Comment: thanks all...the orginal html code is too complicated, and it's not english words....but I've sloved it..

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is malformed. The divs with id="L1" are not closed. And you should not have two elements with the same id.

Comment: thanks Erik, maybe I lost some html code at this question, but I change my jquery function, as show() , I change it to show(normal) and it works now...still can't figure out why.but it did.